# How to connect to oracle object storage using Rest API

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am unable to connect to oracle object storage using Rest Api. when I entered the basic Authentication it shows not authenticated. I also tried using post man the same not authenticated/ un authorised error. But I wanted to connect to oracle object storage in VBCS using Rest which authentication method I need to use?

I tried connecting to object storage using basic authentication, is there any headers I need to use to connect ton object storage using Rest api. I referred this blog https://blogs.oracle.com/vbcs/post/upload-download-files-from-oci-storage-visual-builder
for connecting to object storage to download a file but in this blog the bucket is public, if i have my bucket as private how to connect to it.

This is my Rest API url : [https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/n/{namespaceName}/b/{bucketName}/o/{objectName}](https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/n/%7BnamespaceName%7D/b/%7BbucketName%7D/o/%7BobjectName%7D)

Is this correct ot need to change anything please guide me as step by step

Answer (score 1):

All Oracle Cloud Infrastructure API requests must be signed for authentication purposes. More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/signingrequests.htm)

The post you referred to uses a public bucket but is not recommended. If you do not want to sign the API request, I'd advise using a PAR (Pre-Authenticated Request).